# C# - How to open a file with event even if Windows ask for application by default

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, process, exit

I have an application opening a file (ex: temp.xls, temp.txt, temp.csv, temp.doc, temp.pdf).
I want to attach to it an event on exited.

Only one problem, after the `Process.Start()`, if Windows ask me with which application I would like to open the file (Cause it doesn't have by default), I've an exception one the `process.EnableRaisingEvents = true`.

It seems to me like you can't attach an event on the process if it is not running.

Here is my code :

```
Process process = Process.Start(localPath);
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += OnExited;
```

As for `process.WaitForExit()`, it's causing the same exception.

Here is a code I tried but didn't even pass into the event, as I see:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"path to file";
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.Start();

void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Process exited");
}
```

**Conclusion :**
I want to open a file with an exit event without caring if Windows opens a pop up to ask me with which application I want to open my file.

Comment: Files don't exit. Only applications. What are you really trying to do? Detect when the user closes an Excel instance? Why? Wouldn't it be better to use Excel Interop and control Excel's lifetime directly?

Comment: Are you confusing opening a document with its registered application with somehow "executing" that document?

Comment: PS: `xls` is an obsolete format replaced *15 years ago* by `xlsx`, a ZIP package containing well defined XML files. You don't need Excel to read, create or edit Excel files for the last 15 years. You can use libraries like EPPlus, ClosedXML, NPOI or even the low-level Open XML SDK to generate real Excel files

Comment: I don't care about the xls it was just an exemple.

I want to execute the document yes, if the document is closed, i want to execute a function to check if the document has been modified or not.

No i can't use Excel Interop or i should do this for every existing files, cause "xls" was just an exemple but i want to test it on "txt","xml","csv"... Every type of files

Comment: My conclusion is I just want to open a file with an exit event.

Comment: Documents don't get executed. If you want to check whether a document has changed you'll have to check its `Archive` attribute, its last write time or its hash

Comment: `My conclusion is I just want to open a file with an exit event.` there's no such thing. What are you actually trying to do? You described what you think the solution would look like. What's the actual problem?

Comment: You can use a [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-7.0) to get notified when any file in a folder changes and process it afterwards.

Comment: Yes you right, what i want :
Open a file with his default editor,
If the file is modified,
I want to copy the file in a new directory.